# 'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Items'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have no clue what I am doing wrong, It's just a regular asp.net mvc5 project. this is my controller:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Items
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Price" ? "price_desc" : "Price";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var items = from i in db.Items
                       select i;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            items = items.Where(s => s.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Catagorie.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                break;
            case "Price":
                items = items.OrderBy(s => s.Price);
                break;
            case "price_desc":
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.Price);
                break;
            default:  // Name ascending 
                items = items.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return System.Web.UI.WebControls.View( items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));


        //var items = db.Items.Include(i => i.Catagorie);
        //return View(await items.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Items/Details/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(item);
    }

    // GET: Items/Create
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CatagorieId = new SelectList(db.Catagories, "ID", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Items/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Items.Add(item);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CatagorieId = new SelectList(db.Catagories, "ID", "Name", item.CatagorieId);
        return View(item);
    }

    // GET: Items/Edit/5
     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.CatagorieId = new SelectList(db.Catagories, "ID", "Name", item.CatagorieId);
        return View(item);
    }

    // POST: Items/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CatagorieId = new SelectList(db.Catagories, "ID", "Name", item.CatagorieId);
        return View(item);
    }

    // GET: Items/Delete/5
     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(item);
    }

    // POST: Items/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);
        db.Items.Remove(item);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> RenderImage(int id)
    {
        Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);

        byte[] photoBack = item.InternalImage;

        return File(photoBack, "image/png");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

And I get the following error `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS1061  'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**But on my database I do have the Items table and I am pointing to the right database.**

Comment: Ensure you have declared your set of `Item` in your `ApplicationDbContext` class

Comment: So do you have a property Items in your ApplicationDbContext?

Comment: @Stilgar Yes, I did add controller > and Visual Studio did scaffold all this for me.

Comment: Can you post your data context code.

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    // Rest of data models
}
```

If not, it is a no go.

Comment: I do have that, Visual studio added that when I did scaffold the controller with views.